# How to start a process on main isolate from background task

Tags: flutter, background-process, dart-isolates, flutter-local-notification

In a Flutter app, a background task can be started via a local notification (e.g. onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse from [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin). The main isolate may or may not be active at this point and as far as my understanding goes does not know that the background task was started.

Is there a way for the background task to start a function on the main thread and force a UI update?